# Wordpress giving error when i set up new page

Tags: wordpress

hope someone can help?

Web address: [www.thetalentlocker.co.uk](http://www.thetalentlocker.co.uk)

I have setup a one page site, all worked fine until yesterday. On the one page site, there is a job feed, when clicked you get:

> Internal Server Error
>
> The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was
>   unable to complete your request.
>
> Please contact the server administrator at
>   webmaster@thetalentlocker.revolutionrec.co.uk to inform them of the
>   time this error occurred, and the actions you performed just before
>   this error.
>
> More information about this error may be available in the server error
>   log.
>
> Additionally, a 500 Internal Server Error error was encountered while
>   trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

I have tried to setup a new blank page as a test and get the same error.

I have been looking through Google and a few pointers have been found but not sure if they have anything to do with it, they are:

I am using Godaddy servers and the 'host name is set to 'localhost' is this correct?

Other people say it could be an issue with the .htaccess file?

This is very strange as I have cloned the site and setup another and all this is working fine, this can be viewed at:

[www.j2recruitment.co.uk](http://www.j2recruitment.co.uk)

You can see what the link on the job listing should do.

All very strange and I'm stumped and have a very upset client.

Thanks in advance

Paul

Comment: This comment is offtopic but your name gives me goosebumps :/

Comment: Are you referring to a job page such as: http://thetalentlocker.co.uk/job-2/?ref=4026 - if so in wp-admin go to settings > permalinks and click on "Save Changes" then try loading that page again. Let me know what happens.

Comment: first you need to check the error. this will displaying blank page mean you need to first enable the error through wp-config. set up using  define('WP_DEBUG', true);

Comment: Brilliant, thats seems to have done it, thank you very much